# HDMI not working in Ubuntu 18.04 (Razer Blade 14" 2017)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-monitor

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Razer Blade and I have had a lot of issues with it, most of which I have managed to solve. One thing I cannot figure out though is how to get HDMI working. I am using the nvidia card and xrandr outputs this:
`$ xrandr`
`Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767`
`eDP-1-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x`
`axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm`
(tons of resolutions and refresh rates)
`DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`
`HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)`

Answer (score 0):

I just had a razer blade laptop with GTX 1070 MQ thermal or something. It was using nvidia-435 drivers. None of the hdmi or the thunderbolt was detecting external monitors.

`xrandr` also gives the same output as yours. My solution was to upgrade the nvidia graphics drivers through nvidia's website.

I choose the following options:

```
GeForce
GeForce 10 Series (Notebooks)
GeForce GTX 1070
Linux 64 Bit
```

It redirected me to a download which gave me a .run file, I right clicked it and gave it a permission to be executed as an executable (from properties)

executed it as a super user, it asked me to close everything that uses nvidia gpu, so i did a `prime-select intel` and rebooted the computer (this switches to intel gpu), and I re ran the installation, it failed again for some reason. I switched to nvidia graphics card with `prime-select nvidia` and restarted the computer. Afterwards I launched the `nvidia-settings` app to see the driver version. It said 440, however the ubuntu additional drivers pane says I have 435 installed. When I plugged in the hdmi and the thunderbolt my displays worked.I think it is an Nvidia driver issue.